# how to delete folder with ConsoleApplication backround run process

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have started one executable using `C#`.

Process started code:

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = stopNifiexePath;
Environment.CurrentDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(process.StartInfo.FileName);
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

The `Process.WaitForExit()` line completes. However, when I tried to delete `exe` folder manually, but I can't delete folder. A exception is thrown:

> The action can't be completed because the folder or file in it is open in another program.

Note : `ConsoleApplication6.vshost` process is still running after I have stopped ConsoleApplication. Again I tried to delete `exe` folder manually. The folder is deleted.

How can I delete the folder with `ConsoleApplication` running in background.

Comment: If you have the Console Application opened in Visual Studio the `.vshost.exe` will keep running. Close your Console Application project and try your code again.

Answer (score 2):

Set your current directory away from the directory you're trying to delete. You can't delete it if you're still inside it.

What you probably really want is to set `ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory`, not `Environment.CurrentDirectory`.

So change this line:

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(process.StartInfo.FileName);
```

for this one

```
process.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(process.StartInfo.FileName);
```

Comment: Just replace this line
    Environment.CurrentDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(process.StartInfo.FileName);
with this one
    ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(process.StartInfo.FileName);

Answer (score 0):

Try calling

```
process.Dispose()
```

In the `Process.Exited` event.

Answer (score 0):

You need to force the process to release all resources.  I'd suggest the `using` tag.

```
using (Process process = new Process())
{
    process.StartInfo.FileName = stopNifiexePath;
    Environment.CurrentDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(process.StartInfo.FileName);
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

This will dispose of the process when  `WaitForExit` completes.

Comment: WaitForExit line completed but i can't delete folder